# mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I am new to AI and python, I'm trying to build an architecture to train a set of images. and later to aim to overfit. but up till now, I couldn't understand how to get the inputs and outputs correctly. I keep seeing the error whenever I try to train the network:

`mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (48x13456 and 16x64)`

my network:

```
net2 = nn.Sequential(

nn.Conv2d(3,8, kernel_size=5, padding=0),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),


nn.Conv2d(8,16, kernel_size=5, padding=0),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),

nn.Flatten(),
nn.Linear(16,64),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Linear(64,10)
)
```

this is a part of a task I'm working on and I really don't get why it's not running. any hints!

Comment: What's the shape of your input?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean @Darina, but I think torch.Size([48, 3, 128, 128])

Comment: I'm not a torch expert and could be wrong but it looks to me like the problem is in your linear layer's dimensins. Take a look at this very good article: https://towardsdatascience.com/pytorch-layer-dimensions-what-sizes-should-they-be-and-why-4265a41e01fd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

its because you have flattened your 2D cnn into  1D FC layers...
& you have to manually calculate your changed input shape from 128 size to your Maxpool layer just before flattening layer ...In your case its `29*29*16`
So your code must be rewritten as

```
net2 = nn.Sequential(

nn.Conv2d(3,8, kernel_size=5, padding=0),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),


nn.Conv2d(8,16, kernel_size=5, padding=0),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),

nn.Flatten(),

nn.Linear(13456,64),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Linear(64,10)
)
```

This should work

EDIT: This is a simple formula to calculate output size :

```
  (((W - K + 2P)/S) + 1)
    Here W = Input size
    K = Filter size
    S = Stride
    P = Padding
```

So 1st conv block will make your output of size 124
Then you do Maxpool which will make it half i.e 62
2nd conv block will make your output of size 58
Then your last Maxpool will make it 29...
So final flattened output would be `29*29*16` where 16 is output channels

Comment: Thanks it works now!. can you explain more about the manual calculation I am sorry but I am still learning. or point me to an article.

Comment: I hav edited the answer ....hope you find it explanatory