# RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x128 and 39200x50)

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I'm pretty new at pytorch and CNN modelling and currently trying to implement a Reinforcement learning algorithm (CURL) with my custom environment using pytorch.
The input obs shape is:  `'torch.Size([3,10,15])'`
,with 3 channels, and an image of size 10x15

*Model Architecture :*

```
convs = nn.ModuleList([Conv2d(obs[0],num_filters,kernel=(3,3),stride=2)]) #num_filters=32
for i in range(num_layers - 1): #num_layers=4
    convs.append(nn.conv2d(num_filters, num_filters, kernel=(2,2),stride=1)
OUT_DIM = {2:39, 4:35, 6:31} # for 84*84 inputs
OUT_DIM_64 = {2:29, 4:25, 6:21} # for 64*64 inputs
out_dim = OUT_DIM_64[num_layers] if obs[-1] == 64 else OUT_DIM[num_layers]
self.fc = nn.Linear(num_filters * out_dim * out_dim, self.feature_dim) #self.feature_dim=50
```

*Error :*

> This linear layer breaks the code with an error - ' mat1 and mat2
> shapes cannot be multiplied (1x128 and 39200x50)'

*Analysis :*

I went through the following link - [mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66337378/mat1-and-mat2-shapes-cannot-be-multiplied) and tried to solve my error but couldn't able to do so.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me identify my mistake in my architecture and help me solve it.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

In your question you say your input `obs` is "an image of size 10x15".
However, in your code (in comment) `OUT_DIM` is calculated for either a 84x84 images or 64x64.

Consequently, you have a mismatch between the assumed shape to the linear layer, `num_filters * out_dim * out_dim = 39200` and the actual input size `128`.

Update `OUT_DIM` to correspond to your `obs` shape.

Comment: Yes, you pointed out right. This OUT_DIM is from the actual CURL implementation where they had images of size (84x84) as input. I am unable to interpret what does this OUT_DIM dictionary actually means or does. Could you explain me? probably then I can try and adjust it according to my input.